# Rusting of induction hardened portion when the non hardened portion is chrome plated

Tags: electrostatics, field-theory

When a ferritic steel component that has a portion of it induction hardened and quenched in oil is chrome plated over the non hardened portion, I see rust formation after some time on the induction hardened area.

What could be the reason and solution? I do not de-magnetise the steel after induction hardening before having it plated. Could this be a cause?

Comment: This sounds a bit applied for us poor physicists. You might be better off asking in the [Engineering Stack Exchange](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/).